# Loading a function within an AJAX page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page (orderhistory) where we have an "email" button that, when selected, performs an ajax request and loads an ajax page (emailform) onto a previously "display:none" div.  I want to be able to bind a function onto something on this ajax page.

I realize that I could make this work on the orderhistory page by binding the function upon success of the ajax request.  However, this same ajax page is used all across our website and so it would save a lot of time if I could just add the function into the ajax page and not have to edit each function on each of the host pages that call the ajax page.

The problem I am having is that there is no event to trigger the function.  I can't use $(document).ready because the ajax page is being loaded into a div that is on a document that is already ready.

Am I missing something?  Is there a simple way to do this?  Hopefully I'm being clear.

Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    alert('loaded')
    $('#EmailFrm_Sender').select2();
})
</script>
```

This is the call function.  If I uncommment the select2 function, it'll work on the ajax page.  If I place that same function directly in the ajax page, it won't load.

```
$(".SOEmailLink").click(function(){
  $.get('/SAM/AJAX/BalloonEmailForm.asp', {FormKey:$(this).attr('Formkey'), FormName:('SalesOrder')}, function(data){
    hr_CenterBalloon(data);/*
    $('#EmailFrm_Sender').select2();*/
  })
});
```

It's simple code.  As I stated in comments, if I run this page by itself (with the proper plug in links and jquery file) the functions bind and the alert fires.

Comment: Do you know the elements you want to bind events to in the AJAX loaded page?

Comment: You could write your binding scripts easly in a `<script>` (without $(document).ready or something like this) in the emailform then it will be excuted when the emailform was loaded into the hidden div.

Comment: at the end of the `emailform` you can add a `script` where you binds the events. May be you have to put the event registration using a `timeout` so that by the time the script is executed the elements are updated in teh dom properly

Comment: Try this sample http://plnkr.co/edit/Lr3OFBpl6ebRv5C4YeLo?p=preview

Comment: If the previous didn't work use a timeout execution of scripts as in http://plnkr.co/edit/0aF4z9VmbWIq2l92mcoK?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.  I have tried with $(function(){}) and it won't bind.  I have even set up an alert that I had hoped would pop up as soon as the ajax page loaded but it won't fire.  If I load the ajax page on its own, the function binds and everything works.

Comment: @user2287595 are you using the version of `.load` that only loads a portion of the resulting page into the DOM, or are you loading the entire page?  The former variant strips out `<script>` tags.

Comment: @Alnitak That's actually a good question.  This ajax page is actually being loaded through an older javascript function.  Let me confirm that that isn't the problem.

Comment: @Alnitak  Okay, how it's loading doesn't seem to be the problem.  I tried changing the old javascript/xml request to a jquery $.get but when the function is written in the ajax page instead of part of the callback of the ajax request, it won't fire.

Comment: @user2287595 to be honest it's unclear what problem you're actually having.  Did you try the version in my answer?

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah, I don't feel like I'm doing a great job of explaining it.  I did try the version in your answer and all the answers below multiple times before asking the question.  I just know that if I load the ajax page by itself directly, the function works.  If I load the ajax page into the div by ajax request, the function won't work.

Comment: in which case please show us that loading code.

Comment: @Alnitak I've made the edit showing the call function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for an event to trigger the function.  Just put a call to the function itself directly inside the `<script>` tags in the HTML snippet:

```
<div id="EmailFrm_Sender">
    your form content
</div>
<script>
    // common functions defined here
    ...

    // and then invoke stuff that needs to be run now
    $('#EmailFrm_Sender').select2();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your emailform file:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      alert('LOADED!!!');
    });
</script>
<div>
<!-- form -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, the `$.ajax` function has a success callback you can use to invoke a function like that.